Как задать условие, есть ли элемент в Listbox
Пишу программу, где пользователь вводит имя "папки". Нужно проверить после нажатия кнопки "Добавить", есть ли введенное пользователем имя среди элементов Listbox.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def delete_catalog():
    selection = catalogs_listbox.curselection()
    try:
        catalogs_listbox.delete(selection[0])
    except IndexError:
        messagebox.showinfo('Внимание!', 'Выберите элемент, который хотите удалить')

def add_catalog():
    new_catalog = catalog_entry.get()
    count = catalogs_listbox.size()
    if len(new_catalog) > 0:
        catalogs_listbox.insert(0, new_catalog)
        catalog_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Внимание!', 'Введите название папки!')

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry('390x310')
win.resizable(False, False)

catalogs_listbox = tk.Listbox(width=29, height=9)
catalogs_listbox.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 15))
catalogs_listbox.place(x=49, y=60)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=catalogs_listbox.yview)
scrollbar.grid_forget()
catalogs_listbox["yscrollcommand"] = scrollbar.set

catalog_entry = tk.Entry(width=21)
catalog_entry.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 15))
catalog_entry.place(x=51, y=30)
add_catalog_btn = tk.Button(text="Добавить", width=9, command=add_catalog)
add_catalog_btn.place(y=30, x=268)

catalogs_listbox = tk.Listbox(width=29, height=9)
catalogs_listbox.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 15))
catalogs_listbox.place(x=49, y=60)

delete_catalog = tk.Button(text="Удалить", command=delete_catalog)
delete_catalog.configure(font=('Times New Roman', 10))
delete_catalog.place(x=286, y=278)

win.mainloop()


if new_catalog in catalogs_listbox.get(0, tk.END): что типо этого?
